# Connection string on public repository - EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546909/connection-string-on-public-repository) question I found out how to move connection strings out of web.config.
But I met related problem. In order for Entity Framework to work correctly, I had to indicate my connection string twice:

1. In Connection strings section (which is "movable-to-other-file")
2. In EntityFramework section (which is not)

http://pastebin.com/RNe7vkCH

So, how do you REALLY hide connection strings from *.config files?

Comment: Encrypt your config files... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have [several articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) explaining how to encrypt a connection string in the web.config.

However where I work we use [Octopus Deploy](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files) and use variables that set the connection string based on the environment. We then restrict access for managing the Octopus variables to only the appropriate users.

Comment: As I understood, I make these movements with IIS on my local machine. They will transorm my web.config to secure, unreadable format. 
But how my colleagues on other side of the world will be able to decrypt it? Isn't this encryption process machine-bound? I should provide my colleagues with some kind of key, right?

Comment: The server hosting IIS will be able to decrypt the encrypted configuration string.

Comment: Kane, would ANY IIS web-server be able to decrypt? I'm talking about scenario, when web.config (incrypted) is on the web (in public repo), openly, so anyone could download whole app. So, anyone would be able to decrypt web.config on theirs server? Strange.

Comment: No - there is virtually no chance your configuration will be decrypted. In order to decrypt the configuration you will need to know the `machineKey` which is safely secured. Have a read of the documentation as it should explain how the security works in detail.

Comment: Kane, that's why I keep asking. MachineKey on which machine? When I develope webapp, I do it on my dev-machine. When I deploy to production, I deploy to Azure (and there's no easy way to know machine key), when my colleagues download source code from control version system - they use their own machines. So, somehow, that machine key should be distributed? Right?